# How to align at/after last pattern occurence?

Tags: regex, vim, text, alignment, tabular

Example:

```
this is my text, this is, this is my text
this, this is my, this is my, this is text
this is, my text, this is, this is my text
this, this is my, this is my, this is text
```

Normally, I use [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) plugin to align text.
P.e. to align **at** the 1st or 2nd occurence of `','`
I use this formule:

```
Tabularize /^\(.\{-}\zs,\)\{1}/l0
Tabularize /^\(.\{-}\zs,\)\{2}/l0
```

and to align **after** the 1st or 2nd occurence of `','`

```
Tabularize /^\(.\{-}\zs,\)\{1}\zs/l0l1
Tabularize /^\(.\{-}\zs,\)\{2}\zs/l0l1
```

But how do I align **at and after the LAST occurence ** of `','`
if I don't know how many occurences there are?

Comment: You could anchor your pattern to the end of the line.

Comment: @romainl Anchor to the end of the line?

Comment: Instead of having a pattern that starts with the beginning of the line (`^`), make it work from the end of the line.

Comment: @romainl, I can't make it work. Can you give an example? What do I have to put in `\{1}`?

Comment: Without knowing what exactly the output your looking for I think `.*,` should align after the last comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in vim the last occurrence of a `,` would be matched with `.*\zs,`.

So you should be able to issue a command like `Tabularize /.*\zs,/`

Comment: Thank you. It works fine if I remove the '`^`' from your code :)

Comment: Excellent. I've removed the character.

Answer (score 2):

Though I'm not sure if you'll want to have another plugin just for alignment, but for your information, this can be done pretty easily with [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align) plugin, which defines `:EasyAlign` command for visual mode.

- `:EasyAlign,` (around the 1st occurrences of ,)
- `:EasyAlign2,` (around the 2nd occurrences of ,)
- `:EasyAlign-,` (around the last occurrences of ,)
- `:EasyAlign-2,` (around the 2nd to last occurrences of ,)
- `:EasyAlign-3,` (around the 3rd to last occurrences of ,)
- `:EasyAlign*,` (around all occurrences of ,)

It is even easier if you define a mapping as follows,

```
vnoremap <silent> <Enter> :EasyAlign<cr>
```

then you can do it with just two or three keystrokes.

- `<Enter>,`
- `<Enter>2,`
- `<Enter>-,`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I already checked once this plugin and today again. I just can't make it work. And... there is no way to align at space? There is no regex as well.

Answer (score 1):

A complete regex-based solution is:

`:%s/.*\zs,/,              /g`

then
`:%s/\%>35c\s\{2,}//g` OR `:%s/\%>35c\s\+\(.*$\)/\1/g` to assure not match extra spaces after desired aligned text.

Best regards!